# There has been an error processing your request in magento1.8

Tags: magento

When I click on product name to view product detail on product detail page. This error occured. "There has been an error processing your request" in magento. It was working fine but now I don't know what is the issue. Can anyone guide me?

Comment: first enable local.xml from magentodir/error/local.xml,if it not exiting,then you should get local.xml.sample and rename it....local.xml and track system.log and exception.log

Comment: Thanks Amit, there are 2 files local.xml and local.xml.sample . How to track system.log and exception.log?

Comment: enable log from admin setting admin>system>configuration>   developr